# Can interrupt vector table be resident in CPU?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, interrupt

As far as I know, IVT(Interrupt Vector Table) is stored in the RAM - initialized when booting. But I came across explanations from wikipedia that the IVT resides inside the CPU

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_vector_table#Background

> Most processors have an interrupt vector table, including chips from Intel, AMD, Infineon, Microchip[1] Atmel,[2] NXP, ARM[3][4] etc.

But there are still many articles saying that IVT are stored in the ram

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32511893/8724142

> On a PC the interrupt vector table (IVT) is always located in RAM. By default it's located at 0000:0000 at the start of memory...

I'm quite confused by these two conflicting facts. What is the right explanation?

Comment: The *system* have an IVT. The CPU have a way to point to and access it. It seldom have internal memory for it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for reply. What do you mean by tan?

Comment: Typo...........

Answer (score 0):

Yes, interrupt tables are in RAM.

Wikipedia's phrasing is saying that processors have **a way to use** an IVT, not that it's inside the processor itself.

For example on x86, you can set a new address and table-size with the [`lidt` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt).  x86 calls it a "descriptor table" because there's permission / segment stuff, not just a pointer like on many other ISAs.